# I have an issue to use Prettier in Java

Tags: java, git, prettier

I have an issue on team work with git. Please check this image.[image]

In this image you can see that the two code is really same, but the git doesn't know it and recognized they are different. I am goint to use Prettier to format code style now.
Which option should I set in `.prettierrc.yml` to avoid above issue? Look forward your help. Thank you.

Comment: "*... the two code is really same ...*" - On a syntax-level? Yes. On a formatting level? No. ---  "*Is Prettier good choise for Java programming language?*" - [Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, **tool**, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are **off-topic** for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it.](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)

Comment: git is a file based tool. Are these files identical? __No__. If you know it's java you can tell the differences, while present, have zero effect on what this code 'means'. But, git does not take that into account. Not for java, not for PHP, not for English. Or anything else. As for your further question - SO is not the place for opinions. It's explicitly listed as: Don't ask questions like that.

Comment: @Turing85 Thanks for your advise. But you have misunderstanding of my question. I am going to use Prettier and I just want to know necessary options(like `printWidth, tabWidth, endOfLine`) to write in `.prettierrc.yml` file. to fix above issue.